# Function with memoization, how not to evaluate each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a simple jQuery function that will swap some HTML elements for others when on certain viewports. The idea is simple:

```
<div data-swap-for="#element" data-swap-on="phone"></div>
```

Will insert the element with id `#element` after that line when the current media query corresponds to phone (the details about how that is done are not important).

My function looks like this:

```
jq.fn.swapElements = function(viewport) {

    var targets = jq('[data-swap-for][data-swap-on='+viewport+']');

    if (targets.length) {
        console.log('Found elements to swap for', viewport);

    } else {
        console.log('Found no elements to swap for', viewport);
    }

    return {
        on: function() {
            console.log('Should swap elements for', viewport);
        },
        off: function() {
            console.log('Should restore elements', viewport);
        }
    }
};
```

So whenever the screen enters the phone layout, it calls:

```
jq().swapElements('phone').on();
```

Which should do all the DOM transformations, and when it exits the phone layout, it calls:

```
jq().swapElements('phone').off();
```

Which should restore them.

My problem is that these two are creating a new evaluation of the `var targets...` part, resulting in:

[image: console output]

As the output in the console, and I need this function to cache or remember the variables that it uses, so that the resulting console output is:

```
> Found elements to swap for phone
> Should swap elements for phone
```

That is, only evaluating the elements and saving the variables once per each call (a different `viewport` value should call for a new evaluation).

I've been looking into higher order functions and memoization, but I'm confused about how to apply this in this case and specially to a jQuery function.

Please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use some variable (object or array) to cache already targeted elements.

```
var cache = {}; // Should be out of function

if (viewport in cache) {
    var targets = cache[viewport];
} else {
    var targets = jq('[data-swap-for][data-swap-on='+viewport+']');
    cache[viewport] = targets;
}
```

I Would go with slightly different approach:

```
jq.fn.swapElements = {
var cache;
getTargets: function(viewport) {
    if (viewport in this.cache) {
        return cache[viewport];
    } else {
        var targets = jq('[data-swap-for][data-swap-on='+viewport+']');
        if (targets.length) {
            console.log('Found elements to swap for', viewport);
        } else {
            console.log('Found no elements to swap for', viewport);
        }
        this.cache[viewport] = targets;
        return this.cache[viewport];
    }
}
on: function(viewport) {
    console.log('Should swap elements for', viewport);
},
off: function(viewport) {
    console.log('Should restore elements', viewport);
}
};
```

Pseudocode might not work in particular case, but You get the idea. Whenever You need targets you call `swapElements.getTargets(viewport)` function.

Comment: Is there any way around using a global variable ? Some use of higher order functions or memoization techniques ?

Comment: You could just enclose the entire definition of `jq.fn.swapElements` in an _immediately invoked function expression_ and declare the cache within the scope of that IIFE.

Comment: @Alnitak, but I'm confused about how would I use the ```viewport``` parameter in that case... If I do an IIFE, I would still need to return a function that evaluates ```viewport``` and does whatever with it, no? You think you could help me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't need a higher-order memoize function (although you could trivially apply it when you have written one anyway).

What you need to do is to store the result of `jq().swapElements('phone')` in a variable, and when the screen enters/exits the phone layout you should call the methods on that variable, instead of creating new instances.